# Implicitly bind a controller with a directive through the HTML view code

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an angular controller that does its usual stuff (upon request, calls a service, gets data and saves in its scope). Separately I have a directive whose entire purpose is to make a sliding sidebar menu show and hide (with a slight animation). The menu list is bound to the result of the controller action.

The idea is to make so that by clicking a button somewhere else on the screen:
1. the controller action will be executed
2. on success, the directive will be asked to slide in the menu

I want this to happen without the controller or the directive having the slightest bit of knowledge of each other.

Is it possible to write a binding expression in the HTML code, where upon changing the list of menu items, it will call the directive's `show()` method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve this problem, by introducing a second, utility directive, called `onModelChange`. It uses `ngModel` to listen for changes on the model, and when one does happen, it calls a method on the first directive which is passed as a reference param.

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">

  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.3.15" data-semver="1.3.15" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.15/angular.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainController">
    <a href="#" ng-click="doAction()">Call the controller</a>

    <h2 ng-show="controllerCalled">controller called</h2>

    <a custom-directive ng-click="show()">
      <h2 ng-show="directiveCalled">directive called</h2>
      <h2 ng-show="!directiveCalled">directive NOT called</h2>
    </a>

    <div ng-model="items" on-model-change="show()">
      <div ng-repeat="item in items" >
        <p>{{item}}</p>
      </div>
    </div>

  </body>

</html>
```

**script.js**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('MainController', ['$scope',
  function($scope) {
    $scope.doAction = function() {
      $scope.controllerCalled = true;
      $scope.items = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
    }
  }
]);

myApp.directive('customDirective', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function($scope) {
      $scope.show = function() {
        $scope.directiveCalled = true;
      }
    }
  }
});

myApp.directive('onModelChange', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {
      model: '=ngModel',
      onModelChange: '&'
    },
    link: function($scope, element, attrs) {
      $scope.$watch('model', function(oldM, newM) {
        if (oldM != newM) {
          $scope.onModelChange();
        }
      })
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the correct way is to write a service (or factory) that contain methods and data shared by directive and scope, and controlled by the controller.

A such service will be injected in your directive and your controller.

Comment: then, they would have to know about the service. The issue at hand is that I want the directive to be as minimal as possible, with a minimal state. Making it aware of a service will bring in more boilerplate. This is really a UI issue, that's why I was asking if it couldn't be written as a binding expression - even as a tiny function in the binding expression, if needed